# MotionLayout in AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx, android-motionlayout

I want to use MotionLayout but my app is in AndroidX, I have tried using the usual XML tags but they don't work. The Layout Editor just shows a gray box with the tag name. How do I use MotionLayout in AndroidX, or if that is not possible can you give me an alternative.

Thanks :)

It now happened with GridLayout too. Here are the screenshots:

[image][image]

This is just weird. 
The code for GridLayout:

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content>

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Please, post some code/screenshots so that we can help you. Thanks.

Comment: The `layout_height` property is missing a double-quotation, which could be the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`MotionLayout` was added to ConstraintLayout 2.0 so make sure that you have

`implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$androidConstraintLayoutVersion'`

within your app's `build.gradle` where `$androidConstraintLayoutVersion` is at least 2.0

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without code,
but make sure that you xml tag is right:
`<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout ...>`

Comment: If you require clarification from the asker, please ask so in a comment under the question. If you think the question should be closed for lacking code to reproduce the issue, please flag it.